# cakephp two submit buttons and redirect

Tags: forms, cakephp, submit

trying to create a form that has two submit buttons in cakephp.

task_1 submit button when clicked creates this in the address bar '/fields/add' and sends the information added to the database.

task_2 submit button when clicked creates this in the address bar '/fields/add/add' and sends the entered information to the database`.

task_1 is meant to allow users to keep creating new fields, where task 2 is meant to take them to a different page, at the moment we just chose a page at random.

here is the code for the add function in controller

```
 function add(){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Please Enter Your Invoice Headings');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');   

    $this->Session->setFlash("Please create your required fields.");

    if($this->request->is('post')){

    $this->Field->create(); 

    if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) 
    { 
        if($this->params['form']['task_1'] == "task_1") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Fields','action' => 'add'));
            } 
            if($this->params['form']['task_2'] == "task_2") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Invoices','action' => 'add'));
            } 


    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
    } 
    } 

  }
```

here is the code for the add view

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="add/"> 
        Name: <input type ="text" name="name" /> <br />
        Description: <input type ="text" name="description" /> <br />
        Account ID: <input type ="number" name="accounts_id" /> <br />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" name="task_1" value="Continue adding fields" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="task_2" value="Finish adding fields" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use cakephp form helper in the view?

Answer (score 2):

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Field');
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('description');
    echo $this->Form->input('account_id');//this would be the conventional fk fieldname
    echo $this->Form->button('Continue adding fields', array('name' => 'type_1'));
    echo $this->Form->button('Finish adding fields', array('name' => 'type_2'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
```